# Is there any difference between the notations in case of Markov Chains?

Tags: probability, random-variables, markov-chains

> A Markov Chain $(X_n)_n$ has the following transition matrix:
>   $$P = \begin{bmatrix}
>  0.1 & 0.3 & 0.6\\
>  0 & 0.4 & 0.6\\
>  0.3&0.2&0.5
>  \end{bmatrix}$$
>   with initial distribution $\alpha = (0.2, 0.3, 0.5)$.

Do the following notations mean different things w.r.t. the above information?

- $P(X_1 = 3|X_0 = 1)$
- $P(X_0 = 3|X_1 = 1)$

If Yes, what is that?

Also what does the following mean in case of Markov Chains?

- $P(X_0 = 3, X_1 = 1)$
- $P(X_1 = 3, X_0 = 1)$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability

Comment: @NCh, since, you are linking an Wikipedia page about Conditional Probability, you are insisting that (1) Markov Chain doesn't matter, (2) and based on "(1)" they are same. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: $P(X_1 = 3 \mid X_0 = 1)$ represents the probability that given you begin in state $1$ at time $0$ that you travel to state $3$ at time $1$.  On the other hand $P(X_0=3\mid X_1=1)$ is the probability that given you ended at state $1$ at time $1$ that you began at state $3$ at time $0$.  Meanwhile, $P(X_0=3,X_1=1)$ is the probability that you simultaneously were at state 3 at time 0 and state 1 at time 1, etc...  In the first examples, these are conditional probabilities.  In the latter two examples, these are probabilities of intersections of events.  These have quite different meanings

Comment: You’re asking about standard probability theory notation. The fact that it’s being applied in the context of a Markov chain is largely irrelevant here.

Comment: (*in response to now deleted comment*)  Sure doesn't seem like it to me @user366312.  Rather, it sounds like amd is offering solid advice... that learning notation is equally as important as learning concepts, because it is through notation and language that we are able to communicate mathematics and ideas.  Without a firm grasp on notation, we can neither understand questions, nor present answers in a meaningful way.

Comment: @JMoravitz, I understand the notation. But, if someone tells me that a $(X_n)_n$ is a process which starts at $X_0$ and ends at $X_n$ and then again tells me that the system goes from $X_n$ to $X_0$, that becomes confusing. Coz, that means that the system is travelling the past using some time machine.

Comment: @user366312 noone is saying that we travel *to* the past...  whatever already happened has already happened.  However, so long as we have "forgotten" or "never paid attention" to what happened in the past... then knowledge about the present will give us information about the past.  For example, I go downstairs and open my fridge to find a bottle of milk that I don't remember.  There is a chance that earlier in the day, it wasn't there before but it is more likely that it was actually there before and my roommate purchased it the day before since he prefers to do his shopping on saturday.

Comment: @JMoravitz, add your comments as an answer. I will accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are standard notations from probability theory. Read a comma as “and” and the vertical bar as “given that.” The latter indicates conditional probability; the former a compound event. In particular, $\Pr(X_0=3\mid X_1=1)$ will generally not have the same value as $\Pr(X_0=3,X_1=1)$.

Comment: I’ll add that, judging from your other questions, many of the difficulties that you’re having are a result of your not entirely understanding this notation.